# Where did /usr/lib64 go and what is /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libraries, 64bit

I have two Ubuntu-x86_64 systems.  One is version 10.04, the other 12.04 and there is a difference in the structure of the lib directories.  This doesn't surprise me, but I'm curious if anyone knows why. Is there a good™ reason why?

**10.04**

`2.6.32-38-server #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 4 11:26:59 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
/usr/lib
/usr/lib32
/usr/lib64
```

**12.04**

`3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Debian and Ubuntu are moving to a new [multiarch](http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/) implementation ([spec](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec)).  Among other things, this involves moving arch-specific libraries into `/usr/lib/<triplet>`, dropping the limitations of `lib32` and `lib64` (where will the new [x32 ABI](https://sites.google.com/site/x32abi/) go? where do `qemu`lated binaries live? etc.) as well as extending the package manager to handle mixed-architecture installations much more sanely.

Comment: Thanks for the quick summary and references.  Just when I thought I knew where these things live... The new layout does makes more sense now.