# Don't have directory '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'. But instructions to install a software says './configure --with-ssl-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'

Tags: centos, libraries, nrpe

I am trying to install `NRPE (nagios remote plugin executor)` in a CentOS system. In the configuration step, the document I have been given to refer to says,

```
./configure --enable-command-args --with-nagios-user=nagios --with-nagios-group=nagios --with-ssl=/usr/bin/openssl --with-ssl-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

But the directory `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` is not present in my system. These are the contents of the `/usr/lib` directory:

```
[root@pr2 ~]# ls /usr/lib
lib/     lib64/   libexec/ 

[root@pr2 ~]# ls /usr/lib/
binfmt.d/          grub/              NetworkManager/    sysctl.d/
cpp                kbd/               polkit-1/          systemd/
debug/             kdump/             python2.7/         tmpfiles.d/
dracut/            kernel/            rpm/               tuned/
firewalld/         locale/            sendmail           udev/
firmware/          modprobe.d/        sendmail.postfix   yum-plugins/
games/             modules/           sendmail.sendmail  
gcc/               modules-load.d/    sse2/
```

According to the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43190/where-did-usr-lib64-go-and-what-is-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu), it may be that more modern system have this directory (although the question and answer in the link is about Ubuntu, I think it is safe to assume that the same is true of CentOS systems, since my installation doc for CentOS mentions this directory?). So, **what do I replace the location in the aforementioned command with if I am missing that directory**?

In case it helps, this is the version of CentOS in my machine:

```
[root@pr2 ~]# rpm --query centos-release
centos-release-7-4.1708.el7.centos.x86_64
```

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` is a debian-ism, try `/usr/lib64` instead

Comment: If fedora. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu should be changed to /lib64, either.

Answer (score -2):

'sudo dpkg --add architectire --w file:///home/universal + --all.cache/.fr-O8I2ji/mol-0.9.72.1/file_acsess.deb
(x86_64)'

*that should work*

Comment: Why should they use that particular command? How is it related to the question? Note that they are on a CentOS system (and thus unlikely use `dpkg`). What does the `+` do? Why is the command single quoted?